# Overriding ParentModel class method in Child class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, class, inheritance

I have Parent Model class and viewModel class. Parent Model class has GetViewModel() method and I am trying to inherit Parent class and override the GetViewModel() in Child class.However, it throws an infinite exception.

**Parent ViewModel Class:**

```
public class ParentViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<string> Choices { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }
    public IMetaField MetaField { get; set; }
    public bool IsRequired { get; set; }
    public bool HasOtherChoice { get; set; }
    public string ValidationAttributes { get; set; }
    public string RequiredViolationMessage { get; set; }
    public string CssClass { get; set; }
}
```

**Parent Model Class:**

```
public class ChildModel : ParentModel
{
    public string CorticonEntityName { get; set; }
    public string CorticonFieldName { get; set; }

    public override object GetViewModel(object value, IMetaField metaField)
    {
        this.Value = value;
        return (object)new ChildViewModel()
        {
            Choices = this.DeserializeChoices(),
            Value = value,
            MetaField = this.MetaField,
            HasOtherChoice = this.HasOtherChoice,
            IsRequired = (this.ValidatorDefinition.Required.HasValue && this.ValidatorDefinition.Required.Value),
            ValidationAttributes = this.BuildValidationAttributesString(),
            RequiredViolationMessage = this.ValidatorDefinition.RequiredViolationMessage,
            CssClass = this.CssClass
        };
    }
}
```

I have created two child classes ChildModel class and ChildViewModel classs which are inheriting parent lasses.

I want to override the GetViewModel() of parent class so I have done as below and working perfectly.

**ChildViewModel class:**

```
public class ChildViewModel:ParentViewModel
{
    public string CorticonEntityName { get; set; }
    public string CorticonFieldName { get; set; }
}
```

**ChildModel Class:**

```
public class ChildModel : ParentModel
{
    public string CorticonEntityName { get; set; }
    public string CorticonFieldName { get; set; }

    public override object GetViewModel(object value, IMetaField metaField)
    {
        this.Value = value;
        return (object)new ChildViewModel()
        {
            Choices = this.DeserializeChoices(),
            Value = value,
            MetaField = this.MetaField,
            HasOtherChoice = this.HasOtherChoice,
            IsRequired = (this.ValidatorDefinition.Required.HasValue && this.ValidatorDefinition.Required.Value),
            ValidationAttributes = this.BuildValidationAttributesString(),
            RequiredViolationMessage = this.ValidatorDefinition.RequiredViolationMessage,
            CssClass = this.CssClass,
            CorticonEntityName=this.CorticonEntityName,
            CorticonFieldName=this.CorticonFieldName
        };
    }
}
```

But I don’t’ want set all the properties in child class GetViewModel() again as the parent GetViewModel() is doing.
I wanted to reuse the Parent class method and set new properties in Child class so I tried as below but it is throwing infinite loop.

**ChildViewModel class:**

```
public class ChildViewModel:ParentViewModel
{
    public string CorticonEntityName { get; set; }
    public string CorticonFieldName { get; set; }
    CheckboxesFieldViewModel baseObject { get; set; }
}
```

**ChildModel Class:**

```
public class ChildModel : ParentModel
{
    public string CorticonEntityName { get; set; }
    public string CorticonFieldName { get; set; }
    CheckboxesFieldViewModel baseObject { get; set; }

    public override object GetViewModel(object value, IMetaField metaField)
    {
        object objBase=this.GetViewModel(value,metaField);
        return (object)new ChildViewModel ()
        {
            objParent=objBase,
            CorticonEntityName = this.CorticonEntityName,
            CorticonFieldName = this.CorticonFieldName
        };
    }
}
```

How can reuse the Parent class GetViewModel() without setting the properties again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your culprit is:

```
object objBase=this.GetViewModel(value,metaField);
```

You're calling the same method recursively over and over, blowing up the stack. If you want to call the parent method, you need to use the `base` keyword:

```
object objBase = base.GetViewModel(value, metaField);
```

Comment: KooKzip, Thanks works perfectly but I have a small question. The way which I was doing is correct?

Comment: @Balu Not really, you're breaking the MVC pattern. The viewmodel can reference the model, not the other way around

Comment: I have used composition as I was inheriting from Parent class.